# Need to display object label in combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

**I need to display object label instead of API name in the combobox. How to access label of object dynamically? Below is the scrrenshot and code!**

[image]

*.JS*

```
getCustomObjects({
        })
            .then(result => {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var item = {
                        label: result[i],
                        value: result[i]
                    };
                    this.customObjectOptions.push(item)
                    console.log('this.customObjectOptions : ' + JSON.stringify(this.customObjectOptions));
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                console.log('error ===>: ' + error.body.message);
            });
```

*.html*

```
 <template if:true={showCustomComboBox}>
                    <lightning-combobox name="CustomObject" label="Select Custom Object:" aria-setsize="5"
                        options={customObjectOptions} onchange={handleChange}>
                    </lightning-combobox>
                </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getObjectInfos function of lightning/uiObjectInfoApi
module.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_infos

This will return an array of results where you can get the Label of the objects.

I quickly modified a bit the example of the page to match your requirement but you will need to modify it a bit more still.

To fire the wire you would have to modifty the binded variable with the ApiNames of the objects you want.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfos } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';

export default class WireGetObjectInfo extends LightningElement {
    objectApiNames = [ACCOUNT_OBJECT, OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT];

@wire(getObjectInfos, { objectApiNames: '$objectApiNames' })
wireHandler({ data, error }) {
   if (data) {
     for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                var item = {
                    label: data.results[i].label,
                    value: data.results[i].apiName
                };
                this.customObjectOptions.push(item)
      
     }
   }
}



}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use ```@wire``` method?

Comment: You can return from the apex a List<Map<String,String> or List<WrapperClass> returning  the values builded in apex, for example:

[
     {
       'apiName', 'Account',
        'Label', 'Account',
    },
      {
        'apiName', 'Custom_Object__c',
        'Label', 'Custom Object',
    }
]

This should not being difficult to build as you can use schema class, then in your JS just change the iteration to use:


                        label: result[i].Label,
                        value: result[i].apiName